# Не могу открыть терминал в Linux Ubuntu 22.04.01

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Такая проблема: Хотел открыть терминал в Ubuntu. Пробовал запустить напрямую
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в ответ идет загрузка без ответа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не запускалось. По пробовал сделать через ctrl+alt+f3. Выдало ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же находил на stackoverflow похожую проблему, по пробовал сделать вот такую команду через ctrl+alt+f4:

```
DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus gnome-terminal
```

Так же выдало ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По пробовал написать sudo su, выдало такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подсказать как решить такую проблему?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142274/discussion-on-question-by-kanejons2------linux-ubuntu-22-0).